# Parsing SQL Server Database's Script

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, parsing

I'm currently working on a project which is responsible to generate database model based on its schema, I want to know is there any library in *.Net* which is able to parsing SQL Script file and allows me to:

1. Get Database name from script
2. Get Tables name
3. Get each table's columns
4. and anything you know for generating model

Any advice will be helpful.

Comment: "I'm currently working on a project which is responsible to generate database model based on its schema" - erm , VS 2008 and VS2010 already have this ability: Database Project. Failing that SMO...

Comment: My application is a web base application which will be hosted on none-dedicated server, So it can't access to database directly. I want each user able to upload the script file and download generated model.

Comment: You could look at [Microsoft.Data.Schema.ScriptDom](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gertd/archive/2008/08/21/getting-to-the-crown-jewels.aspx) for parsing TSQL Scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is more than I expected

[ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/)

[SQLParser](http://www.sqlparser.com/)

[Fantastic Tutorial-SQL Parser](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/SQL_parser.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any library for this work except SMO. it is better that you have a query on sql system schemas. please see the below script as an example:

```
SELECT 
    SPECIFIC_NAME as SpName, 
    PARAMETER_NAME as ParameterName, 
    DATA_TYPE as DbType, 
    CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH as Size  
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS 
 WHERE PARAMETER_MODE = 'IN' OR PARAMETER_MODE = 'INOUT'
```

This script get the stored procedure parameters. or

```
SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.yourTableName')
```

for getting table columns.
I recommend to you that don't use SMO.

Comment: What do you have against SMO? Can you clarify **why** you wouldn't use SMO??

Comment: I always have problem with new versions. it is my opinion.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: I'm reading SMO overview, Is SMO able to do what requirements I posted ?

Comment: Yes.  SMO has gotten a bad reputation in the past: most problems with it can be fic=xed. Might be of interest: http://mitch-wheat.blogspot.com/2011/07/fixing-slow-sql-server-management.html