# Security-check for custom SQL SELECT query in C#

Tags: c#, sql, security

I need to verify that a run-time user-supplied SQL query is only used to SELECT data - and can in no way execute other operations (delete, update, insert, ..) or alter the database (alter, create, drop, truncate, ...)

I am not looking for a restricted-user solution (may be implemented later), but for a C# query "white-listing".

Currently, this is the code I am using :

```
    private bool ValidateDatasourceQuery(String datasourceQuery)
    {
        bool result = false;

        try
        {
            bool isValid = true;

            String query = datasourceQuery.Trim().ToLower();

            if (query.Substring(0, 6) != "select") { isValid = false; }

            if (query.Contains("delete ") || query.Contains(" delete")) { isValid = false; }
            if (query.Contains("exec ") || query.Contains(" exec")) { isValid = false; }
            if (query.Contains("insert ") || query.Contains(" insert")) { isValid = false; }
            if (query.Contains("update ") || query.Contains(" update")) { isValid = false; }

            if (query.Contains("alter ") || query.Contains(" alter")) { isValid = false; }
            if (query.Contains("create ") || query.Contains(" create")) { isValid = false; }
            if (query.Contains("drop ") || query.Contains(" drop")) { isValid = false; }
            if (query.Contains("truncate table ") || query.Contains(" truncate table")) { isValid = false; }

            result = isValid;
        }
        catch (Exception exception) { GUC_Utilities.TraceError(exception); }

        return result;
    }
```

Any thoughts and ideas? Are there ways to pass through this check and execute a dangerous operation like DELETE? How would you improve this code?

Also another question, is ExecuteReader method only able to run SELECT statements, or could also run other CRUD operations? Like in the following code :

```
                //execute command
                SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlConnection);
                SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
                dataTable.Load(sqlDataReader);
```

Thanks for your time!

PS I am only interested in improving & validating the given code - no GUI, specific roles & other suggestions are currently an option

EDIT (2014-01-16) : After further research and tests, I can confirm that there IS NO RELIABLE WAY to prevent hackers injecting destructive statements inside your SQL query (semicolons, character injections, built-in functions, etc.). The only way to maintain data integrity is TO CREATE A SPECIFIC USER ROLE WITH LIMITED SET OF PRIVILEGES. Everything other must be considered as potentially unsafe. As well, note that EXECUTEREADER can indeed run DELETE, UPDATE and INSERT statements.

Comment: Why not add the security in the DB? Just give the user used to connect to DB Read permissions.

Comment: What about `SELECT * FROM whatever WHERE somevarchar="drop"`

Comment: It looks like it would be saner if the user could just supply the columns to retrieve and where condition using a data structure that allows for tighter control, and make your code create the actual query.

Comment: @Adarsh It's not an option - the same user can run a large number of predefined safe queries containing any operation .. And there are thousands of users and all are sharing the same connection string.

Comment: @SJuan - impossible, user must be able to run complex SELECT statements containing multiple joints etc.  - the freedom to create any SELECT query is a must.

Comment: So you want the user to have the functionality of a SQL console without the risks of a SQL console. Good luck with that. Follow @AdarshShah advice, and use a different connection with restricted permissions for this kind of task.

Comment: In fact, if possible I would not use a different user but an entirely different DBMS (with a copy of the database) so the user does not kill your operations DB when he forgets to write a proper WHERE clause.

Comment: Transact-SQL doesn’t require spaces to separate tokens; you could also use other whitespace and even comments.

Comment: @Gumbo - do you think that you can find a query other than SELECT which would not be detected by the provided C# code? If yes, could you please share an example?

Comment: @EugenRieck this is a safe code that is supposed to be whitelisted - and will be because the match pattern also includes a space

Comment: You have some sort of grey-list here - at minimum, it should be a strict whitelist (allow `SELECT` only) - what happens if a new dangerous command is added?  Which is going to highlight the first large problem: you won't always find `SELECT` in the first six characters - you're eliminating CTEs, which can be a _huge_ help in certain types of queries.  It might help to know what the anticipated dataset is - if you work for a clothing company `"Alter"` is likely a common string...  Heck, I'm assuming there's an `"Executive"` job title at your company... and Unicode might still bite you.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse : 100% agree with your comments .. there might be some valid fully requests that will be rejected because they contain reserved words as substrings ; right now the only way to deal it is to have the user submit it to us directly, so we can check it and allow the request manually ... until a better solution, I was looking for ways to improve my verification code

Comment: @Vlad [T-SQL allows comments within SQL keywords](http://ferruh.mavituna.com/sql-injection-cheatsheet-oku/#InlineComments), so `SEL/*comment*/ECT` would work.

Comment: @Gumbo - thanks for the information, I am learning new things here .. will probably also blacklist comments in user scripts!

Answer (score 2):

Sqldatareader creates a forward only data reader. Selects are the only statements that will work.

As an aside selects with any sort of logic especially if they will be reused should be turned into a stored proc to allow for plan generation and caching.

Comment: important notice : it is not true that sqldatareader only accepts SELECT statements - DELETE works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

How about wrapping it in a transaction, read the data then always roll back the transaction. So if an malicious code is present it will never get committed.

Comment: I just wanted to say, what a great idea! Upvote didn't seem enough.

Answer (score 2):

jus add-

> Select * from ( your Query Here)x

Only Select Queries will be run and other will give an error.

Comment: yes, 
but...what happened in case i have an Order By in my query??
Sql Server doesn t allow it...

Comment: @user3061212 uh can check this out .... **Select * from ( SELECT *,rownumber = ROW_NUMBER() over(order by employeeCode desc) FROM employee )x** .. Although its not perfect but works perfectly and about rownumber column uh have to hide it.

Answer (score 1):

While what you have looks like in some cases it might work, I'd think about taking it a step further and parsing the query for real. [Parsing SQL Server Database's Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137191/parsing-sql-server-databases-script) points to a few items that might be of interest. Then you can learn to ask the syntax tree what is really going on and make decisions based upon that. There's really no security in what you've done. And I can think of a few ways someone who's smart enough could get through your security. If it's an internal app though, you need to consider if the effort is worth it or not.

Comment: indeed, this post proposes few existing vendor tools for parsing SQL queries, so they can easily be validated, while preventing injection attacks etc. thanks for the information! by the way I would really appreciate if you could share a way to get through (if you have some time)

Answer (score 0):

How about using the [Builder Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) along with a suitable GUI allowing the user to build the query?

Comment: no extra tools and funky GUIs, text-only. i know that the method is not 100% safe, but right now I am just trying to validate (& improve) the given code to the best extent, as written in the question :)

Answer (score 0):

this might work better, this allows the keyword to appear if its a part of a bigger alphanumeric string:

```
public static bool ValidateQuery(string query)
{
    return !ValidateRegex("delete", query) && !ValidateRegex("exec", query) && !ValidateRegex("insert", query) && !ValidateRegex("alter", query) &&
           !ValidateRegex("create", query) && !ValidateRegex("drop", query) && !ValidateRegex("truncate", query);
}
public static bool ValidateRegex(string term, string query)
{
    // this regex finds all keywords {0} that are not leading or trailing by alphanumeric 
    return new Regex(string.Format("([^0-9a-z]{0}[^0-9a-z])|(^{0}[^0-9a-z])", term), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).IsMatch(query);
}
```

you can see how it works here: [regexstorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5B%5E0-9a-z%5Ddelete%5B%5E0-9a-z%5D%29%7C%28%5Edelete%5B%5E0-9a-z%5D%29&i=11%20delete%20drop%0D%0Adelete%20*%20from%20%0D%0A%3Bdelete%20*%20from%0D%0Aselect%20*%20from%20table%3Bdelete%20*%0D%0A11delete%20%0D%0A%20deletedrop%0D%0A%27deletedrop%0D%0A11deletedrop%0D%0A)
see regex cheat sheet: [cheatsheet1](http://image.slidesharecdn.com/regex-cheatsheet-100421095826-phpapp01/95/regex-cheatsheet-1-728.jpg?cb=1271843931), [cheatsheet2](http://www.cheat-sheets.org/saved-copy/regular_expressions_cheat_sheet.png)

notice this is not perfect since it might block a query with one of the keywords as a quote, but if you write the queries and its just a precaution then this might do the trick.

you can also take a different approach, try the query, and if it affects the database do a rollback:

```
public static bool IsDbAffected(string query, string conn, List<SqlParameter> parameters = null)
{
    var response = false;
    using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(conn))
    {
        sqlConnection.Open();
        using (var transaction = sqlConnection.BeginTransaction("Test Transaction"))
        using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConnection, transaction))
        {
            command.Connection = sqlConnection;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            command.CommandText = query;
            if (parameters != null)
                command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters.ToArray());
            // ExecuteNonQuery() does not return data at all: only the number of rows affected by an insert, update, or delete.
            if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
            {
                transaction.Rollback("Test Transaction");
                response = true;
            }
            transaction.Dispose();
            command.Dispose();
        }
    }
    return response;
}
```

you can also combine the two.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the comment that is used in most of the cases for SQL Injection:

```
if (query.Contains("--")) { isValid = false; }
```